# Is riding a bicycle in the parks of Glasgow allowed?

Tags: uk, bicycles, scotland, glasgow

I have heard that bicycles are not allowed in some parks in London, so I thought that maybe in Glasgow the council has the same rule.

Are they forbidden in Glasgow? Does it depend on the park?

Comment: Is this really a travel question?

Comment: @pnuts: Sure, but that doesn't make it a travel question. Just because a traveler does something does not make a question about that thing on-topic. Travelers brush their teeth. Asking how to brush your teeth isn't on-topic here. :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about regulations which affect locals equally as travelers.

Comment: @pnuts: That question only applies to travelers, as, by definition, only travelers use long-distance trains.

Comment: @Flimzy I'm going to travel to Glasgow and there is several parks there. I wanted to know if I can hire a bike to visit them or if I should take the tube and visit them by walking.

Comment: @JCalcines, Glasgow isn't London. It doesn't have a tube. It has a very limited sub way. Your best bet for public transport is the buses.

Comment: @Flimzy if I ask whether the water in Sevilla is safe for brushing my teeth, it should qualify as a travel question...

Comment: Bike use isn't forbidden in London parks. There are bike routes (around or through) at least Hyde and Regents park. Certain pedestrian routes are off limits.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No policeman is going to arrest you for riding in a park. I'd be surprised if you can't ride in all the parks in Glasgow (or almost any other city in the UK) for that matter.

Give pedestrians the right of way and be considerate and you'll be fine.

Comment: A pavement is defined as a footway by the side of a road. So avenues in parks are not pavements, and it is not illegal to cycle there. Also the Scottish Outdoor Access Code gives a general right of access, which would include cycling through a park (so long as you are responsible).

Comment: "A pavement is defined as a footway by the side of a road."  Where?  In what text?

Comment: @JoeBlow in common usage as might reasonably be understood by a reasonable person. You'll notice that the [relevant laws](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/Will4/5-6/50/section/72) ([Scotland](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1984/54), s.129) a) don't say pavement but also b) don't actually define the terms they use.  The law isn't a formal grammar.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, riding a bicycle in the parks of Glasgow is allowed.

Now even more so that there are new bicycle rental schemes in place, right at the entrance of parks.